# Creating Form with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models, a User and Patient. A User HAS_ONE Patient and a Patient BELONGS_TO a User.

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
  attr_accessible :user_id, :user_attributes
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: patients
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  insurance  :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :patient

  attr_accessible :username, :password, :active, :disabled, :first_name, :last_name, 
  :address_1, :address_2, :city, :state, :postcode, :phone, :cell, :email
  attr_accessor :password
end


# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                 :integer         not null, primary key
#  username           :string(255)
#  encrypted_password :string(255)
#  salt               :string(255)
#  active             :boolean
#  disabled           :boolean
#  last_login         :time
#  first_name         :string(255)
#  last_name          :string(255)
#  address_1          :string(255)
#  address_2          :string(255)
#  city               :string(255)
#  state              :string(255)
#  postcode           :string(255)
#  phone              :string(255)
#  cell               :string(255)
#  email              :string(255)
#  created_at         :datetime
#  updated_at         :datetime
#
```

In my patients controller I am trying to create a new Patient form.

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @patient = Patient.new
  end
end
```

In My View (new.html.erb)

```
<%= form_for @patient do |patient_form| %>
<% patient_form.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>
<table class="FormTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            <%= user_fields.label :username %> *:                       
        </td>
        <td class="input">
            <%= user_fields.text_field :username, :class=>"TextField" %>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
...
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

The form shows up blank with a submit button with no generated markup for the user_fields

I have been told I am doing this wrong because of the patient having the accepts_nested_attributes_for :user and it should be the user nesting the attributes BUT in my system I want to use the resources model so a patient and other user types are treated separately.

Example Database table:

USERS:     id|first_name|last_name...etc

PATIENTS:  id|user_id|insurance

Comment: What do the logs say? Have you tried going into the rails console to check for errors?

Comment: Says nothing.. The page renders just an empty form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, you have no `user` when you are calling `fields_for`. Before you can do the `fields_for`, you will need to have an instance of a user that can be used to build the form, kind of like how you have `@patient` for your `patient_form`.

Your best bet would be to build a `User` in your controller, based off of your `@patient`, and then you will have access to that in the view.

Answer (score 1):

try `<%= patient_form.fields_for` with the equals sign in there?  I know there was a warning message for awhile about "block style helpers are deprecated".

Answer (score 0):

The answers from Jeff Casimir and theIV are correct, but you need to do them both. I.e., fix the `patient_form.fields_for` block to user `<%=`, and build a User object for the Patient in the controller, something like:

```
def new
  @patient = Patient.new
  @patient.user = User.new
end
```

Comment: Has this always been the case? I thought that `form_for` and `fields_for` were always `<% -%>`.

Comment: It changed from Rails 2 to Rails 3: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html, see 7.4.2