# accepts_nested_attributes_for issue in Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Before asking this, I have already tried with the solution detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094008/creating-form-with-accepts-nested-attributes-for), but it didn't work.

context: 2 models, Idea and Project. 1 idea belongs to 1 project, 1 projects has many ideas.
I want to create a form to create ideas that have fields of ideas but also to specify which Project they belong to, by indicating the **project_id** field. I'm doing it with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Issue: I'm not being able to grab the project_id when creating a new idea from a form. From the console I see that a new idea has been saved, but project_id for that idea always returns nil

code:

ideas_controller.rb

```
# GET /ideas/new
def new
@idea = Idea.new
@idea.build_project

respond_to do |format|
format.html # new.html.erb
format.json { render json: @idea }
end
```

models> idea.rb

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :project

accepts_nested_attributes_for :project

mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
validates :name, presence: true, allow_blank: false

end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@idea) do |f| %>    
<% f.fields_for :project do |project_fields| %>
<% if @idea.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@idea.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this idea from being saved:      </h2>

  <ul>
  <% @idea.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
<%= f.label :name %><br>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :description %><br>
<%= f.text_area :description %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :picture %><br>
<%= f.file_field :picture %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :project %><br>
<%= f.number_field :project_id, :class=>"Number" %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: change this `@idea.build_project` into this: `@idea.project.build` maybe it will help.

Comment: Nope, it crashes and returns a undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass on the line edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records through the `parent`", according to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html). you are doing it through the `child`, which I don't think is possible.

So either move the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to the parent model and use the `parent's` form to create the `parent` fields along with the `child` field. so you'll be creating `project` and `idea` through the `projects_controller` and `projects/_form.html.erb`

or opt out for something else.

without using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, add `project_ids` to your `ideas` params attributes as an empty array:

```
def idea_params
   params.require(:idea).permit(:name, :project_ids => [])
end
```

`app/views/ideas/_form.html.erb`:

```
 <div>
    <%= idea.label 'File under at least one project' %>
    <% Project.all.order(name: :asc).each do |project| %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "idea[project_ids][]", project.id %>
      <%= project.name %>
    </div>
</div>
```

this code will give you checkboxes of your projects to select. this means first you have to create the projects separely in project's own controller and form. so you are not using nesting attributes.